# $(window).scroll not working in Internet Explorer (11)

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

The following jQuery is working in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari but not IE11. In IE11, you have to scroll back up to the top and then scroll down to get it to work.

I'm linking to jQuery Version 3.2.1.

```js
$(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
      $('.contents:hidden').css('visibility', 'visible');
      $('.contents:hidden').fadeIn('slow');
    } else {
      $('.contents:visible').fadeOut('slow');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"   integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="contents">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#1">Return on Surplus</a></li>
    <li><a href="#2">Underwriting</a></li>
    <li><a href="#3">Investment</a></li>
    <li><a href="#4">Combining Underwriting &amp; Investment</a></li>
    <li><a href="#5">Application &amp; Analysis</a></li>
    <li><a href="#6">Key Takeaways</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script>
```